# Cant open two terminal windows in elementary

Tags: linux, terminal, elementary-os

I am currently using Elementary OS. Some while back I could open up more than one terminal just by "Win+T" but now I just cant. The first terminal opens up without a hitch. However the second one just does not show up no matter what I do. Anyone knows how to fix this? 
P.S. the terminal command being used is "io.elementary.terminal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default shortcut to open terminal is <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-T</kbd>.
I had the same issue after some unknows update on my machine. I fixed this by disabling System terminal shortcut and added custom shortcut.

The command that is used to fix this is `io.elementary.terminal -n` The `-n` flag stands for *new window*.

[image: custom shotcuts window]

**Edit:** i got this problem when i switched from bash to zsh.